# Pre Calculus Simplifying Trigononmetric Expressions

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to simplify this trigonometric expression in terms of sine and cosine. The equation that I have to simplify is 7 cos t tan t.

Comment: Although we appreciate your interest in Mathematica and Stack Exchange, you really should do this analysis by hand in order to learn trig.

Comment: I am trying to do it by hand but I don't how to. I know that tan t simplifies to sin t over cos t but after that I am stuck because when I try to get rid of the 7 cos then the other side has the 7 cos. Please tell me  how to do it.

Comment: `7 Cos[t] Tan[t]` simplifies to `7 Sin[t]`.

Comment: what is $\tan t$ in terms of $\sin t$ and $\cos t?$

Comment: On method you can use is to always convert all the trig ratios to fractions in terms of O,A, and H.  So your expression would convert to $7\frac{A}{H}\frac{O}{A}$